# Customising Default Navigation Drawer Activity Vector Icons

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop, drawable

I'm trying to customise and colourise the default `Navigation Drawer Activity` on Android Studio 2.1.2. I've changed the color of `ic_menu_camera.xml` file in following way--

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#f73a3a" //changed colour
        android:pathData="M12,12m-3.2,0a3.2,3.2 0,1 1,6.4 0a3.2,3.2 0,1 1,-6.4 0" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#f73a3a" //changed colour
        android:pathData="M9,2L7.17,4H4c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v12c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h16c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2V6c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2h-3.17L15,2H9zm3,15c-2.76,0 -5,-2.24 -5,-5s2.24,-5 5,-5 5,2.24 5,5 -2.24,5 -5,5z" />
</vector>
```

The colour changes in the preview window as per screenshot below-

[image]

However, colour is changed again to default black/dark grey when the app is launched--

[image]

How can I implement the changed color here?

Comment: My understanding is some styling file is overriding the drawable colours. but can't figure out which one.

Comment: Any ideas on how to change the icon to my own JPEG image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `setItemIconTintList` to null during `onCreate`

```
YourView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Now you can edit the vector assets directly and the changes will show.